# Post request body with file and text

Tags: c#, .net, http, postman, multipartform-data

In the Windows application, I have to upload the text file to the server, for that I am using the post APIs where I have to pass the file parameter and text parameter.

I have tried the `MultipartFormDataContent` for doing the same but somehow file upload is happening, and the params are not through the request body.

Attaching the postman request body: [image: PostMan request Body]

Code I have tried using `MultipartFormDataContent`:

```cs
RequestJson requestJson  = new RequestJson ();
requestJson.uploadFile = FilePath;  // string Path of file
requestJson.userName= "Nation";
requestJson.email = "Nation@xyz.com";

HttpContent postData = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestJson ), Encoding.Default, "application/octet-stream");
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Add(postData, "upload", "file3.txt");

Task<HttpResponseMessage> message = client.PostAsync(ServerUrl, content);
```

Comment: Don't see you have add any properties of `requestJson` to the `content`.

Comment: If you check , I have added postData which have all 3 parameters

Comment: `HttpContent postData = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(headerUploadLogs), Encoding.Default, "application/octet-stream");` No, don't see `requestJson` in your mentioned `postData` line.

Comment: Just updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, you have to add the property one by one to the `MultipartFormDataContent`.

```
content.Add(new StringContent(requestJson.email), "email");
content.Add(new StringContent(requestJson.userName), "userName");
content.Add(/* File Content */, "uploadFile", "file3.txt");
```

You can work with *System.Reflection* to iterate each property in the `RequestJson` class as below:

```cs
using System.Reflection;

foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(RequestJson).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.GetProperty|BindingFlags.Public))
{
    if (prop.Name == "uploadFile")
    {
        var fileContent = /* Replace with Your File Content */;

        content.Add(fileContent, prop.Name, "file3.txt");
    }
    else
    {
        content.Add(new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(prop.GetValue(requestJson))), prop.Name);
    }
}
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xI6rLD)

Comment: As we have to upload a text file which can be 10-30 mb in size , plus filecontent should be type of HttpContent, still fileContent is ambiguous

Comment: In short, append the property one by one to `MultipartFormDataContent`. You can't append the whole `requestJson` as single object to `MultipartFormDataContent`.